# Can't get ggplot to produce a geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am kind of new to r so sorry if I don't make a lot of sense, but I have been plotting data fine with geom_line, but for some reason this line is not showing up. I am not getting any errors or anything though.
Code:

```
ggplot(data=ABB, aes(x=Label1, y=Average, color=factor(Native))) +
  geom_line(size=.2) + 
  geom_point(size=.6) +
  labs(
    title = "Alton Baker Park Bloom Rates",
    y = "Week First Seen",
    x = "Year Seen"
  ) +
  theme_simple +
  theme(
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(size=20),
    axis.title = element_text(size=14),
    axis.text = element_text(size=10),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size=10),
    axis.line = element_line(size=.5)
  )
```

Heres what I'm getting

[image]

There is a lot of data but here is some of it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MKQe.png)

Comment: We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Is your x-axis data coded as a factor or character (rather than as numeric)? You can check with `str(ABB$Label1)`. If so, then try `geom_line(aes(group=1))`. When the x-axis data are categorical, ggplot treats each category as a separate group. But ggplot only draws lines between points that are in the same group. `group=1` (or `group="anything"`) overrides the default behavior. Alternatively, convert `Label1` to numeric.

Comment: first thing i'd do is remove all the theme stuff until i get the plot working, so i'd remove everything after the `geom_point`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data looks something like this, I'm not sure why it's not working for you...can you share your data?

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    year = c(1990:2010, 1990:2010),
    value = c(runif(21, 0, 5), runif(21, 4, 10)),
    species = c(rep('Invasive', 21), rep('Native', 21))
  )

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=year, y=value, color=factor(species))) +
  geom_line(size=.2) + 
  geom_point(size=.6)
```

[image]